# C macros with states

Tags: c, preprocessor

Is it possible to have C macros with any sort of state? In this particular case, an integer value.

I want to be able to allocate some memory from statically allocated buffer, since I am in an embedded environment. Say I have a struct like this and a buffer:

```
double buffer[1000];

typedef struct {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    double* data;
} matrix;
```

I would like to have macro that can generate a matrix and allocate the relevant memory from the buffer in question. However, I cannot seem to think of a way to keep an internal counter of where in the buffer we should be at the moment. Ideally, the macro would be something like:

```
#define alloc_matrix(_rows, _cols) {.rows = _rows, .cols = _cols, .data = &buffer[PTR]}
```

where PTR is compile time constant that is constantly changing (increasing by rows * cols) for every usage of alloc_matrix. This would allow me check if everything fits the buffer during compile time using something like _Static_assert, instead of checking everything during runtime.

Is this possible with the C preprocessor?

I have tried using the C preprocessor but can't seems to find a way to store a state in the macros.

Comment: Add a global counter, and increment it in each invocation of the macro.

Comment: `PTR` would have to be a global variable.

Comment: No, macros do not have any state of their own, but that's the wrong question.  *Your program* needs to maintain state that belongs *to it*.  You *can* use macros to generate code that accesses and modifies the variables where you store that state.  Once you define those.

Comment: This is doable at compile time in C++.

Comment: With that said, however, you probably ought to be using functions, instead.

Comment: Why does it have to be shared data buffer for all matrices? Traditional way would be to have declare 2 static variables for each matrix separately: one for matrix data, and one for matrix struct. No need for any macro nonsense.

Comment: It's the linker's job to allocate space for your variables and make sure they fit in the desired sections.  Can you just declare global variables for all the matrix data separately and use the linker to arrange them?  Also, don't think about macros yet until you know how to write the correct code.  Then use macros to make the code succinct, if appropriate.

Comment: X-Y problem for sure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible if you think outside the box. Why must you be allocating chunks pointing into a pre-allocated array?

Instead, consider making a struct containing nothing but `double` array members. Such a struct wouldn't have any padding or alignment problems. It will grow in size as you add more members, all at compile-time.

Rolling out the infamous but ridiculously flexible "X macros", we can declare all our matrices/arrays in an abstract list:

```
#define DATA_LIST(X)        \
/*  name    rows cols */    \
  X(data1,  5,   7)         \
  X(data2,  2,   2)         \
  X(data42, 42, 42)         \
```

Now create a struct type based on this:

```
typedef struct
{
  #define MATRIX_MEMBER_DECL(name, rows, cols) double name [rows][cols];
  DATA_LIST(MATRIX_MEMBER_DECL)
} matrix_t;
```

This expands to:

```
typedef struct
{
  double data1 [5][7];
  double data2 [2][2];
  double data42 [42][42];
} matrix_t;
```

An instance of this struct will take up exactly that amount, no more, no less. We need not pre-allocate an arbitrary chunk and try to assign pointers into it.

```
matrix_t matrix;
printf("double items:  %zu\n", sizeof matrix / sizeof(double));
printf("Total size:    %zu\n", sizeof matrix);
```

This gives:

```
double items:  1803
Total size:    14424
```

(1803 * 8 = 14424, so there was no padding as predicted)

You may access individual matrices/arrays like you would any struct member:

```
matrix.data42[0][0] = 3.1415;
```

Wanna know the row or column size of `data42`? Make a corresponding enum for look-up:

```
typedef enum
{
  #define MATRIX_MEMBER_ROWS(name, rows, cols) name##_##row = rows,
  DATA_LIST(MATRIX_MEMBER_ROWS)
} matrix_row_t;

#define MATRIX_GET_ROWS(name) name##_##row

...
printf("%d\n", MATRIX_GET_ROWS(data42)); // prints 42
```

And so on. This is all 100% pure compile-time calculations.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to give up the requirement that all matrices use shared data buffer, you could use compound literals here:

```
#define alloc_matrix(r, c) {.rows = (r), .cols = (c), .data = (double[(r)*(c)]){0}}

// Allocate immutable matrix with mutable data space
static const matrix MyMatrix = alloc_matrix(3, 4);
```

But please remember that if you want static storage duration, then this works only outside functions; when compound literal is defined in function, it will have automatic storage duration.

Comment: A quick note, C23 standard will allow `static` storage duration for compound literals.